# Por que me da error al recorrer con foreach un ObservableCollection en C#

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, aplicación-movil

Estoy haciendo una consulta a firebase y el resultado lo guardo en un ObservableCollection de Un modelo de carrito de compras, que es el siguiente:

```
ObservableCollection<MCarrito> _Carrito;

public ObservableCollection<MCarrito> Carrito
        {
            get { return _Carrito; }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ref _Carrito, value);
                OnpropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Guardo los datos con este metodo:

```
public async Task PintarCarrito()
        {
            var funcion = new DatoCarrito();
            Carrito = await funcion.ListarCarrito();

            foreach (var item in Carrito)
            {
                Total++;
            };
            
        }
```

Pero el foreach no se ejecuta, no me deja recorrer el listado y si le doy Carrito.Count me sale error, no se que estoy colocando mal, muchas gracias.

El metodo listar Carrito es el siguiente:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<MCarrito>> ListarCarrito()
        {
            var data = await Task.Run(() => Cconexion.firebase
                  .Child("Carrito")
                  .AsObservable<MCarrito>()
                  .AsObservableCollection());
            
            return data;
        }
```

Comment: que es esto? SetValue(ref _Carrito, value);.... y que error sale en el Count? y donde esta el count? y que hace ListarCarrrito? y si listar carrito devuelve una coleccion, para que la tenes como propiedad? hay muchas cosas raras por ahi...

Comment: Es que estoy utilizando arquitectura MVVM y hace herencia a la clase BaseViewModel, el count no lo puse ahí, listarCarrito lo que hace es consultar en firebase y devolver la observableCollection y lo guardo en esta que tengo como propiedad.

Comment: ok.. pero que tiene que ver SetValue? tene en cuenta que no hay un patron estandar de MVVM, cada uno puede hacer la clase como quiere. El Task pintar carrito esta en la misma clase que la definicion?

Comment: ListarCarrito devuelve una observableCollection?

Comment: Si devuelve un observableCollection

Comment: Entonces, no esta devolviendo nada.. no es null? seguis sin decirme que error tira el count...

Comment: Acabe de hacer una prueba y el count me devolvió cero, pero no entiendo si el listarCarrito me devuelve un observableCollection, este observableCollection sea null, es el primer proyecto que manejo con C# no se muy bien del lenguaje, perdona mi ignorancia, y si en vez de observableCollection uso un List, entonces si me deja recorrerlo.

Comment: porque haces task.run? no es un metodo async? estas seguro que esto .AsObservableCollection()); devuelve el mismo tipo de coleccion que vos esperas?